# Commiting a JPA transaction after remove

Tags: jpa, transactions, entity, one-to-many, optimistic-locking

I am having a specific scenario, where 2 tables are having parent child relationship. When i m invoking the api to delete a child, it works fine. And then when I try to invoke the api to delete the parent, I get optimistic lock exception.
Upon investigation, I realized that while deleting the parent, it is trying to delete the child as well which has already been deleted.

Below is my code snippet. Any suggestion or help would be great.

This is the code for deleting the child.

```
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)
    public void deleteChild(int id) {
        var child= entityManager.find(Child.class, id);
        entityManager.remove(child);
    }
```

And this is the code for deleting the parent.

```
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)
    public void deleteParent(int id) {
        var parent = entityManager.find(Parent.class, id);
        entityManager.remove(parent);
    }
```

The Parent entity has OneToMany relationship with the Child entity.

```
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private List<Child> child;
}
```

Comment: You must remove the child from the parents list

Comment: The remove(child) operation completes successfully but while removing the parent it shows up again... Somehow the removeChild is not committing i guess...